# Yii : how to redirect to a place while the tbl is empty?

Tags: php, yii

I would like to check the tbl "Is there are data exists?". If the data isn't exists at tbl I want to redirect to one page. How can I do without placing the same code at the actions of all controller?

```
if(Company::model()->exists() == false)
            $this->redirect(array('site/create'));
```

Comment: You can use beforeAction in components/Controller.php

Comment: GBD <<< I placed my code into components/Controller.php. But it is not effected. I'm using rights extension. so I placed my code into modules/rights/components/RController.php. At that time I got this error.
*****
Declaration of RController::beforeAction() should be compatible with CController::beforeAction($action)***** How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have this logic run before every action of every controller you can override the [`run`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#run-detail) method of the base controller class (usually this is named `Controller`; you will find it inside the `protected/components/` directory).

Here's an example of how to do it:

```
public function run($actionID) {
    if ($this->route != 'site/create' && Company::model()->exists() === false) {
        $this->redirect('site/create');
    }
    else {
        parent::run($actionID);
    }
}
```

Comment: This webpage has a redirect loop :)

Comment: @tharsoe: The only thing that can go wrong here is the `$this->route` check. You will have to debug it and see why it's different than the example.

Comment: working :D :D thx Jon

*****
public function run($actionID) {  
     if ($this->route != 'site' && Company::model()->exists() === false) {
         $this->redirect(array('/site/create'));
     }
     else {
         parent::run($actionID);
     }
 }*****

Comment: @tharsoe: You should probably check for both `site` and `site/create`, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to perform a query, and if there are no results redirect to another page?

```
$model = YourModel::model()->find("your query goes here");

if (empty($model)){
    $this->redirect("redirect/url/here");
}
```

If you want to execute this on every page "load", you can put it in the Controller.php (*protected/components/Controller.php*) by creating an **init** function like so:

```
public function init() {
    // anything here will be executed when any controller/action is called
}
```

Comment: yes of course. And my code is working fine. but where should place those code? I don't want to place those code into all of the actions of controllers and models.

Comment: Well, when do you want to check if there is data? Every time a page loads?